# Getting started with open graph protocol

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I have been trying to work with facebook code.  Specifically I read about open graph protocol. I have tried to apply this to my page at http://www.fjkluth.com/grepq33.html.  Especially there is a like button on the page.  But though the like button appears there is no response from facebook when I paste the link into a comment space on a wall page.  Facebook seems to be unable to read the urls coded into the page. There no title posted on the wall nor is facebook able to post a thumbnail. Facebook provides a debugger but the response is very cryptic and I cannot understand it.

Comment: It would be good to show the cryptic response nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Object Debugger for your page:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fjkluth.com%2Fgrepq33.html

is indicating that Facebook is scraping an empty document from your url (this link is at the bottom of the debugger page):

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fjkluth.com%2Fgrepq33.html

It appears something is interfering with Facebook's ability to GET the real contents of the page.